# Ozonolysis: mechanism for reductive workup of ozonide using Zn/Acetic Acid/Water

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the mechanism for the reductive workup of an ozonide using zinc/acetic acid/water? Many sources online show the mechanism using DMS instead:

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/alkenes-alkynes/alkene-reactions-tutorial/v/ozonolysis-1

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcO49xCb4Gs

Comment: Use a pair of electrons on Zn metal the same way that one uses an unshared pair on dimethyl sulfide.

Comment: @user55119 can metals act as nucleophiles?

Comment: @user55119 so I tried the mechanism using zinc as the nucleophile. Would you get ZnO as the product in addition to the carbonyl compounds?

Comment: @user55119 In acid? It looks like typical reduction with hydrogen *in statu nascendi*.

Comment: ZnO or likely zinc acetate ultimately.